# If my question is duplication a common historic reference then point me to it

Tags: discussion

I don't believe thatmy specific question of [why we didnt use official, full force in the Bay of Pigs](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/34056/why-invade-cuba-in-such-a-weak-manner) exists as common info on the web.

Your close reason claims exactly that. So if the specific information I asked for exists "commonly" on the web, then link me to one example explaining the reason we used non official forces rather than going in with trained troops in full force.

That information didnt show up for me on a Google search. So either point me to an online document and paragraph, or page that contains this informationyou claim my question is requesting a duplicate of (in which case I'll eat my words and be on my way) or change the close reason, or re open my question.

If my question needs to be closed, I have no problem with that but close it for the right reason, please.

Comment: just realized I forgot to add a link on the title when I posted this, sorry about that. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

On this site there's often a significant difference in knowledge between people asking and answering questions. This can shape how questions are asked and interpreted, and this can make a complex question seem trivial (or vice versa). With source searches on Google, the difference of a single keyword can often change no useful results into dozens of useful results - again, making a request seem trivial.

To get the question re-opened; I would suggest that you edit the question to highlight exactly what you want to know, include some references to the sources you've already found (SE has an expectation of prior research) and explain why your question isn't answered to your satisfaction by these sources. In this particular case, you seem to give a perfectly valid answer in the question (i.e. keeping US involvement a secret) so it would help to say why you don't think this is the true reason.

Comment: Im not claiming I dont think my guess was the true reason. but it was the guess of a person not educated in history beyond the highschool level, with no formal training in diplomatic and war strategy or historical knowledge of those topics, so I decided to ask about this curiosity and learn the truth rather than just go for a guess. I read a wikipedia article, what do I need to do read a book in the JFK library before Im allowed to ask a question here?

Comment: My original post, without any editing, describes a question that is not common info quickly available on the web (i.e. not explained in the wikipedia page). Some comments and answers explained that fairly well already. i just don't like people misusing a public resource, wrongly closing my question when it's a valid, arguably interesting history question. It already had a pretty good answer on it, why close it?

Comment: There are a list of close reasons, not a text box for you to write the close reasons, for the same reason a judge cant write a new law to convict you of because he doesn't find you likable. Those close reasons being limited is a feature meant to keep people from closing questions for the wrong reasons. You can't just apply a random reason and close it. Thats like a police officer not finding me likable and putting me in jail and just putting down a random charge as the reason because he can't figure out a specific law I broke. The question is valid.

Comment: `Im not claiming I dont think my guess was the true reason` Edit to this comment I made, after realizing the part of my question you were referring to. This was wrong, according to an answer that looks pretty good, it wasnt because they believed they could keep this manner of attack secret, but so that they could claim lesser involvement than an all out US attack. The president of the US knows full well that the info would come to light at some point that the US was involved, this sentence in my question was just saying "This is the only reason I can think of (but obviously thats not right)"

Comment: You're not expected to be an expert before posting but by including the sources you've read, such as the wikipedia page, you let people know what you're already aware of. That will stop people simply quoting the most obvious source(s) back to you as an answer and will often prevent the question being closed as being trivial. If you can also explain where these sources fall short for you, it helps people form an answer by filling in those particular gaps in your knowledge.

Comment: agreed and corrected.

Answer (score 1):

There are only a few close reasons, which means that we have to choose the closest. We don't have the luxury of precision.  If you want to know why your question was closed, the logical place to start would be to examine the comments.

- the first and last comment pointed out that your question didn't address the information commonly available in wikipedia. Note that there are seven upvotes for these comments, which should be a significant clue to answer the question you've asked here.    If you want to re-open the question, please edit the question to address these comments.
- The question ndicated little or no research. Your question in this forum indicates that you don't believe that the information is on the web. The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bay_of_Pigs_Invasion#Later_analysis) article includes an entire section on post-conflict analysis.   Google provides 380,000 suggested results, the first of which is an analysis from the [JFK library](https://www.jfklibrary.org/JFK/JFK-in-History/The-Bay-of-Pigs.aspx), which ought to be pretty credible.  As the site help files suggest, H:SE exists to supplement Wikipedia and Google, not to replace them.   In May of 2014 the first comment alerted you to the problem, but you provided no response.  One of the best ways to demonstrate that you've done the preliminary research is to provide a link to the research. and a comment indicating why that research didn't answer your question.
- asked "Why not" - Questions that ask why something **didn't** happen are always marginal - the site conventions clearly indicate that speculation and alternative history are off topic.  Historical sources and methods can be used to analyze things that did happen, but even with history that actually happened, history can't always provide a credible causality.   Once we cross the border into analyzing things that didn't happen, historical sources and methods are much weaker.  I think there is some latitude for military questions because post-action analysis is a common part of military history. If you'd addressed some of the other issued, the question might have passed muster.
- Your question provided three assertions without supporting evidence (they were funded, they were armed, they were supplied), and implies that those three facts should have led to victory. If military planning were that simple, the Secretary of Defense would be paid a lot less.  War is an adversarial endeavor; just as no battle plan survives contact with the enemy, there is frequently no clear cut cause for actions and outcomes.  These unsupported, unsourced, non-trivial assertions cause the question to read less like a request for a historical answer, and more like political speech.  If you want to re-open the question, you might flip these assertions into questions. (Note: this is my opinion; there are others who will disagree because they feel that subquestions are anathema.)  If you're really asking for an analysis of the relative importance of funding, armament and logistics in the success of this military action, then ask that question.

In my personal opinion, the quesiton is on the edge. It isn't a period of history that interests me, and I personally am strongly turned  off by questions that demonstrate no preliminary research.  If the issues above were fixed, I might be more inclined to vote to re-open.